# Creating a database instance in C#

Tags: sql-server, database, c#-4.0

Is it possible to create a sql database instance with C# code.  I have no problem adding a database to an existing SQL instance, for example WONEA\SQLEXPRESS but for creating another SQL instance such as WONEA\SQLEXPRESSTEST I'm a little stumped.  Help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is you can't do this using C# code.

SQL server instances are essentially installations of SQL server - in order to create a new SQL server instance you need to run the SQL Server installer, and ask it to install one (which you can technically do from C# code, but I gather thats not the answer you were looking for).

Answer (score 0):

Creating new instances requires running the installer for SQL server, so I would imagine the answer is "No."  (Would be interested to hear otherwise though!)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a command prompt process to create a SQL instance if you have SQL Local DB installed.  See code example below:

```
Process proc = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo
{
     FileName = "cmd.exe",
     Arguments = $"/C {argument}",
     RedirectStandardOutput = true,
     UseShellExecute = false,
     CreateNoWindow = true
};

proc.StartInfo = info;
proc.Start();
```

Where *Argument* is a string parameter that looks something like this:

> sqllocaldb create "SqlInstance"

This instruction will create a new SQL instance called *SqlInstance*.